# How to detect checkbox checked or not using react native?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In my scenario, I am trying to write a logic for `checkbox` check or `uncheck`. if check means need to print some string or uncheck mean need to print something else. how to achieve this using react native?

my code below

```
checked={this.state.checked}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.actiondone();
                }}

actiondone(){
   //Here how to detect checked or not with if else
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your state to achieve this. If your state is currently checked (`this.state.checked = true`) when you press the checkbox, then the intended state is unchecked, and vice versa. Then you can set your state to be the opposite of what it was.

So basically you do the opposite of the current state of the checkbox, then set the state to be the desired state (asynchronous).

Something like the below:

```
<CheckBox
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onPress={() => this.actionDone()}
/>

actionDone() {
    if (this.state.checked) {
        // Do what you want when the checkbox is unchecked
    } else {
        // Do what you want when the checkbox is checked
    }

    // Set the checkbox to the desired state
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
}
```